# I don't have the ">" and "<" symbols on my keyboard how to assign a shortcut to type them

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts

I code a lot and I need to easily access the "less than" and "greater than" keys, but for some reason my keyboard doesn't have those two keys. This is the layout that I'm using, and I can press all the keys except the <kbd>></kbd> and <kbd><</kbd>.

[image: keyboard layout]

So how do I solve this? Is there a way to replace one of the keys that I don't use very often with `>` and `<` or assign a shortcut to them or something?

Comment: see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674021/how-to-type-less-greater-than-characters-in-us-keyboard-with-non-us-layou), you can do smth like that

Comment: It seems useful but it's a lot of work, i'll try it anyway

Answer (score 2):

With your keyboard layout, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> produces "<", <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> produces ">".

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> is the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Comment: my right alt key is "Leve3 S..." on that layout, so i tried shift + that alt + z or + x and it's not working

Comment: I think the order of pressing the keys is significant.. Following the sequence in the answer does nothing on my English (UK) keyboard either but changing the sequence to AltGr+Shift+Z (or X) performs as expected.

Comment: it's works for me too on the UK keyboard but not in the frensh one

Comment: looking at your keyboard layout, the > and < key is to the immediate right of the Left Shift key - a multi function key. I don't have an AZERTY keyboard here so not sure how they are accessed but worth trying different combinations.

Comment: That < and > button can't be accessed with my keyboard because my keyboard doesn't have that button i don't know why